# Windows virtual machine over remote desktop stuck at "To Improve the appearance of visual elements, ..."

Tags: remote-desktop, hyper-v

I was installing Windows on a VM where the VM Server was accessed via remote desktop.  Eventually install was stuck at "To Improve the appearance of visual elements, Windows will automatically adjust your screen resolution" and I couldn't click the button.  The entey key and the space key don't work.  Since the mouse isn't available on the VM yet, anyone know how to close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pressing the tab key until you see the OK button highlight, then press enter.

If that doesn't work, try entering Fullscreen mode in Hyper-V with Ctrl-Alt-Pause, then use the tab key.

Comment: fullscreen is not working with remote desktop.  It turns out alt-pageup worked in this case.